# Function to check status of gravityforms wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to make a function to check if the gform has some entries, has all entries or is empty and return $status according to status.

I have looped through the entries and checked if they are infact shown as an empty string if empty but I only ever get partial or empty.

```
function set_form_status($form_id) {
    $entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, entry_search_criteria());
    $status = '';
    if (count($entries) > 0) {
        foreach($entries as $entry) {
            $keys = array_keys($entry);
            foreach($keys as $key) {
                if ($entry[$key] === '') {
                    $status = 'partial';
                }
                if ($entry[$key] !== '') {
                    $status = 'filled';
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
    $status = 'empty';
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running it like below and seeing what gets returned. I did remove the entry_search_criteria function but other than that I'm just echoing the key/value.

What I found was even if I'm not using purchasing in a form, there are fields created for it and they are empty. They don't show on the back end entry view even if I select show empty fields. You may have a similar scenario.

```
function set_form_status($form_id) {
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id);
$status = '';
if (count($entries) > 0) {
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        $keys = array_keys($entry);
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            echo $key . ' - ' . $entry[$key] . '<br>';
            if ($entry[$key] === '') {
                $status = 'partial';
            }
            if ($entry[$key] !== '') {
                $status = 'filled';
            }
        }
    }
} else {
$status = 'empty';
}
return $status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, the issue I was having was a **HTML** field returning an empty string. I did some refactoring and got some help for my co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

Did some refactoring and debugging together with a co-worker, there was **HTML** fields on all of the forms and all of them returned an empty string. This is the working version.

```
function set_form_status($form) {
    define('FORM_EMPTY', 0);
    define('FORM_PARTIAL', 1);
    define('FORM_FILLED', 2);
    //checks if the form is my special kind of form
    if (is_eligible_form($form)) {
        $earlier_entry = get_last_entry($form['id']);
        if ($earlier_entry === false) {
            return STATUS_EMPTY;
        } else {
            foreach($form['fields'] as $key => $field) {
                if ($earlier_entry[$field->id] === '' && $field->type !== 'html') {
                    return FORM_PARTIAL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FORM_FILLED;
}
```